# Why does my WriteLine loop terminate prematurely?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a function to read from a file, and another to write to a file. The file I am trying to read and write is the numbers from 1 to 3000 in order. I read the file just fine and store it in a variable called `numbers`. For some reason, when I write the file, it writes the first 2913 lines correctly, but this is the end of the output:

```
2908
2909
2910
2911
2912
2913
2
```

The file ends in the middle of number 2914 every time I run the program. The program does not throw an exception. Why does this behavior occur?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Main() As Integer 
    Dim numbers As New List(Of String)
    ReadFile(numbers, "C:\test.txt")
    WriteFile(numbers, "C:\test2.txt")
End Function

Private Sub ReadFile(ByRef lines As List(Of String), _
                     ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        lines.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub WriteFile(ByVal lines As List(Of String), _
                     ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, False)
    For Each line In lines
        sw.WriteLine(line)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, you can replace all that code with two lines: `numbers = File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.txt")` and `File.WriteAllLines(numbers)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also avoid this with a `Using` block:

```
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, False)
        For Each line In lines
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Next
    End Using
```

If you get into the habit of typing "Using" instead of "Dim", then it forces you to think about the "End Using" portion which automatically closes and disposes of the stream.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I did not close the `StreamWriter`. By adding a `StreamWriter.Close` to the `WriteFile` method, I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: you should make sure you close your StreamWriter in case of an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I assume I should do the same for the StreamReader?

Comment: indeed! i would use a TRY-CATCH-FINALLY statement, closing both the streamreader, streamwriter in the FINALLY statement in the end, ensuring that block of code is executed regardless of any exceptions that may or may not have occured.